# Why 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' happens when overwrite 'initWithCoder' method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came across the exception '`NSInternalInconsistencyException`' when I write the code below in a `viewcontroller` which is associated with storyboard:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, if I delete the line '`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`', there is no problem. I don`t know the reason.

Actually, in the stroyboard I have several controllers, and I want to make a base controller for all the controllers. The purpose is that I want to set a background view(UIView) for them.

I try to add a `UIView` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the basecontroller, but the view covers any components that set in the storyboard. I think the reason is that the components on the sub viewcontrollers are initialized in the '`initWithCoder`' method before the '`ViewDidLoad`' method is called. So I try to add the bgView in the 'initWithCoder' method of the basecontroller, and this led to the problem above.

So I also want to know a right way to achieve my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: What's the entire error message?

Comment: Why don't you do it in the simple way via adding it in the viewDidLoad like you said and then sending it to the back so that it cannot cover other views. It will go into the most backward position when you will call the viewDidLoad on super so that will be it.

Answer (score 1):

dont set graphics related properties in init and bring subview to front. Set them from

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```